# Twitter Widget inside Google API InfoWindow using jQuery, AJAX, and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3, twitter

Thank you for all your help, in advance.

My purpose is to display a Twitter widget within the InfoWindow of each marker on a map created from the Google Maps API. The following is an explanation of how I go about it. The main problem lies within the AJAX code.

1. On the map, when I click on a marker, data is retrieved from a database regarding the marker. This data then appears in the InfoWindow of the marker. Some of the data includes code for a Twitter widget that is unique to the marker.
2. This Twitter widget needs to be written into another file, timeline.php. I have tried to this with AJAX.
3. On index.php, I have an iframe of timeline.php inside the code that displays InfoWindow content. This will display the twitter widget within the InfoWindow.

Here is the code:

On index.php...

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

      $.ajax({
            url: 'timeline.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data  : {twitter: val[8]}, 
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                },
                error : function(err, req) {
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                }
       });

         infowindow.setContent(
            "<div class='marker_title'>"+val[0]+"</div>"
            + "<div class='marker_uri'><a target='_blank' href='"+markerURI+"'>"+markerURI_short+"</a></div>"
            + "<div class='marker_desc'>"+val[4]+"</div>"
            + "<div class='marker_happy'>Happy Hour: "+val[7]+"</div>"
            + "<div class='marker_address'>"+val[6]+"</div>"
            + "<div class='marker_edit'>"+"<a href='#modal_add' class='btn btn-large btn-success' data-toggle='modal'><i class='icon-plus-sign icon-white'>);"+"Edit this location"+"</a>"+"</div>"
            + "<iframe src='http://www.peopleofparty.com/radhatest/represent-map/timeline.php'></iframe>");

         infowindow.open(map, this);
         });
```

On timeline.php

```
<?php
     echo htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['twitter']);
?>
```

You can see all this in action on http://peopleofparty.com/radhatest/represent-map/

As you can see, the result, is just a blank area in the InfoWindow where the Twitter widget should be. The dialog box that pops up shows up is evidence that the Twitter widget is being written into timeline.php, from what I know.

Again, much thanks.